# How do I write a Firestore security rule so that only someone who is listed as an admin can perform certain actions and everyone else can only read?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

The structure is:

```
/groups/{groupID}
```

Inside this {groupID} record, it will have the following fields (the last one is a subcollection). The `adminUID` listed in this collection is the one who should have the extra permissions.

```
groupID
groupName
adminUID
adminUsername
createDate
creatorUID
creatorUsername
initialGroupCreate
groupMembersSubcollection
```

For the static fields, the admin should be able to:

- create the {groupID} record with these static fields, cannot modify/delete

The members of the group can only read but not write/delete.

For the subcollection, the admin should be able to:

- create/delete any number of records in the groupMembersSubcollection; cannot modify

The members of the group can only read records in this sub-collection.

Comment: I have updated my answer with your missing rule.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Firestore collection structure is as follows and your documents inside `groupMembersSubcollection` saved with document id as `group Members` `user.uid` :

```
Firestore Database
└── groups - (Collection)
    └── {groupID}- Document Id
        ├── groupID
        ├── groupName
        ├── adminUID
        ├── adminUsername
        ├── createDate
        ├── creatorUID
        ├── creatorUsername
        ├── initialGroupCreate
        └── groupMembersSubcollection - (sub-collection)
```

Then your desired security rules will be as follows :

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        // function to check member or not
        function isMemerOrNot(groupId) {
            return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(groupId)/groupMembersSubcollection/$(request.auth.uid)); // Not verified
        }

        // Rule 1: Static fields in the groups collection
        match /groups/{groupId} {
            allow read : if request.auth != null && isMemerOrNot(groupId);
            allow create: if request.resource.data.keys().hasAll([ //making sure all fields are there while creating this document
                'groupID', 
                'groupName', 
                'adminUID', 
                'adminUsername', 
                'createDate', 
                'creatorUID', 
                'creatorUsername', 
                'initialGroupCreate']) &&
            request.resource.data.adminUID == request.auth.uid; // allowed only for admins
            allow update, delete: if false; // No updates or deletes allowed
        }

        // Rule 2: groupMembersSubcollection
        match /groups/{groupId}/groupMembersSubcollection/{userId} { 
            allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId // Members can read the subcollection
            allow create, delete: if 
            request.auth.uid == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(groupId)).data.adminUID;
            allow update: if false; // No updates allowed for subcollection documents
        }
    }
}
```

##### Explanation :

1. For Rule 1 :

- The `read` rule will only allow authenticated users which are also members(for isMemberOrNot function you need to check whether a member with that uid exist or not you can use `exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(groupId)/groupMembersSubcollection/$(request.auth.uid)) ;` technique from [Access other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) but you need to be sure that the subcollection have the member documentId as a document already exist )
- The `create` rule allows only the admin to create a document in the groups collection with the specified static fields.
- The `update` and `delete` rules are set to `false` so that no one cannot modify/delete

2. For Rule 2 :

- The `read` rule allows authenticated users and Group Members to read the documents in the `groupMembersSubcollection` with the help of their `user.uid`.
- The `create` and `delete` rules allow the admin (using `adminUID` from parent document to identify) to create or delete documents in the `groupMembersSubcollection`
- The `update` rule is set to `false` to disallow any updates to the documents in the `groupMembersSubcollection`.

Reference :

- [**Requiring specific fields in new documents**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields#requiring_specific_fields_in_new_documents)
- [**Access other documents**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents)

Comment: The first rule is missing the part that handles this (from the question): `The members of the group can only read but not write/delete`

Comment: @whatwhatwhat I have updated my answer with your missing rule as you.